# Line break so each flex-item is a row of three?

Tags: html, css

This is my code taken from a tutorial:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    

.flex-parent {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  margin: 13px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* =========================
   GENERAL STYLES 
   NOT RELATED TO THE TUTORIAL
============================ */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --clr-primary: #ee6352;
  --clr-secondary: #d16e8d;
  --clr-accent: #f7f7ff;
  --clr-gradient: linear-gradient(
    -90deg,
    var(--clr-primary),
    var(--clr-secondary)
  );
  --ff-title: bungee, sans-serif;
  --ff-body: canada-type-gibson, sans-serif;
  --fw-body: 300;
  --fw-bold: 800;
  --fw-title: 400;
  --fw-number: 800;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: var(--ff-body);
  font-weight: var(--fw-body);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  width: min(95%, 45rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      flex-item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It works and is functional, but the problem is I cannot get it as three flex-items per row, meaning after the third, it moves to a new line etc.

I've got the spaces in-between working with:

```
.flex-item {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  margin: 13px;
}
```

Margin set at 13px

What I cannot do is try and get these to have three flex-items per row without having to cut-and-paste flex-parent class each time.

I'm trying to keep this design simple.

This is far from production, just a sandbox.

If you could guide me on things it's appreciated!

Comment: flex-wrap:wrap on the flex-parent